# Datetime conversion problems

Tags: datetime, stata

I'm currently working in
Stata on a dataset by which the year and quarter are given as 'YYYY QQ' in a string. I am trying to split this into year and quarter using the year and quarter functions. However, I keep getting a type error and have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Those functions require a numeric argument and in any case the numeric argument should be a Stata daily date. There are various better ways forward for you. One is to use the `split` command with the `destring` option.

```
clear 

set obs 1 

gen given = "2022 3"

split given, destring

rename (given?) (year quarter)
```

You likely need a quarterly date any way and the function for that is `quarterly()`.

```
gen wanted = quarterly(given, "YQ")
format wanted %tq 

list 

     +----------------------------------+
     |  given   year   quarter   wanted |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 2022 3   2022         3   2022q3 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

See `help datetime` for basic documentation.